# Multidimensional scaling with missing values in dissimilarity matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, missing-data, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a dissimilarity matrix on which I would like to perform multidimensional scaling (MDS) using the [sklearn.manifold.MDS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html) function. The dissimilarity between some elements in this matrix is not meaningful and I am thus wondering if there is a way to run MDS on a sparse matrix or on a matrix with missing values? 
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529646/nan-inf-values-in-scikit-learn-manifold-learning-functions) question, dissimilarities with 0 are considered as missing values, but I was unable to find this statement in the official documentation. Isn't a dissimilarity with value 0 interpreted as points that are very close to each other?

Any suggestions how to obtain a lower-dimensional representation of my high-dimensional dataset based on a sparse dissimilarity matrix would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint to that question! I looked into the code: 
For zeros on the non-diagonal to be interpreted as missing values you need to use the non-metric version of the MDS using the SMACOF algorithm by `MDS(metric=False)`.

I have the same issue and until now I only see the alternative to do [matrix completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion) on the distance matrix before applying MDS.

Answer (score 0):

**Similarity = 1 - Dissimilarity**

If you have *Dissimilarity=0*, Thus you're having *Similarity=1* & thus, your points are similar in your space